# Invert printing colors?

Tags: printing, printer, colors

The other day I installed a bulk ink system for my printer and then realized that the cyan color and the magenta were swapped, so, when I try to pint blue, it actually prints green, and so on.

Is there any way to print the right colors using only software? (I know I could fix it by just changing the ink cartridges, but since they're apparently full I'm afraid I could do some damage to the printer).

Comment: Just swap the cardridges. This should not harm you nor the cardridge nor the printer given that you don't force things when they're not giving in.

Comment: Do it right rather than introducing layers of complication that will last forever.  Disconnect the problem colors as close to the head as possible, flush the residual wrong ink if you can, and reconnect it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.

I think you can change this in the color profile settings.

Right click on your printer. Figure out how to go to color management. There will be something called add color profile. Check the name.

Color profiles are usually installed in the systemroot\System32\Spool\Drivers\Color folder.

You can go here and edit the profile.